# Code organisation and design for re-usable mail-client library

Tags: php, design-patterns, class-design

I have now few projects that make use of `imap_*` set of functions from PHP IMAP extension.

The task is to fetch mails from mailhost do some processing and based on results, store them in DB or reply to mail (in ie. invalid task request format)

Working with the `imap_*` functions is a very low-level task, with a lot of repetitive code, so I get to the point that I should implement some unified lib that will cover the imap functions and let me work on a high-level, well defined classes / interfaces / object factories etc.

Question is how I should organize classes/code for this task? I know that badly designed library is worst than no library at all :)

**[EDIT]**

My initial idea was to create the `Transport` class that will wrap the connection, hide the mailbox handle (result of `imap_open`) inside the private property, and use of `imap_*` functions via `__call` magic.
Secod class would be the `AccessManager` that will use `Transport` class and take care of mail fetch logic, and mayby also third `Message` object factory? Or `Message` class should have some `::createFromSomething()` static initializer?

Comment: What has been your initial idea on how to organize this? An idea would be to map out any common sets of data that you notice is used together alot and make it into a class. For instance you could have a Message class to hold data related to a single message, then Server to hold functions that do any actual server interaction along with the server configuration (host, authentication) variables, etc etc

Comment: I've descireb my initial idea in question body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create the following classes:

- ImapClient (GetFolders, SendMessage, Search)
- FolderCollection
- Folder (GetMessages)
- MessageCollection
- Message

Comment: Hmm... I totally forgot about *Collection objects, thanks for hint. PS `IMAP` php ext cannot send mails through mailbox handle (`imap_mail()` is only a wrapper for limited standard php `mail()` func)